# Отправка коментария на email автора статти

Tags: python, django, python-2.x

Есть форма для коментировании статьи, нужно что бы при отправке формы на сайт она так же отправлялась на email автора который создал статью! 
Вопрос в том как правильно достать email автора статьи когда он не зарегестрирован и отправить ему сообщение!

```
if request.POST and ("pause" not in request.session):
    form = CommentForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        comment = form.save(commit=False)
        comment.comments_author = request.user
        comment.comments_article = Article.objects.get(id=article_id)
        author = Article.objects.get(id=article_id)
        form.save()

        mail_subject = 'You have a massege'
        message = render_to_string('blogs/masege_to_email.html', {
            'user': comment.comments_author,
            'author': author

        })

        to_email = author('email')
        email = EmailMessage(
            mail_subject, message, to=[to_email]
        )
        email.send()

        request.session.set_expiry(60)
        request.session['pause'] = True
return redirect('/articles/get/%s/' % article_id)
```

Comment: Если не зарегистрирован, то откуда доставать?

Comment: Я имел в виду, что пользователь зарегестрированный но не активный. Но тем немение уже разобрался как сделать. Спасибо!